# MacBook Pro error report

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

I received the following error report from my MacBook Pro:

```
UUID: 334D8DD6-1F4F-4E65-8D2A-D8EC96CE2E52
Stackshot Reason: Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while entering darkwake on way to sleep. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74.
Failure code:: 0x9e233908 00000031

================================================================
Date/Time:       2019-06-04 07:34:17 +0200
OS Version:      ??? ??? (Build ???)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  28

Data Source:     Stackshots
Shared Cache:    0x104ef000 0790ECA1-FEA2-34B5-977F-9114E6FBC1CC

Event:           Sleep Wake Failure
Duration:        0.00s
Steps:           1

Time Awake Since Boot: 360000s



Process:         kernel_task [0]
UUID:            4170BF94-38B6-364F-A1B0-2F7C2C30F9A9
Architecture:    x86_64
Version:         Darwin Kernel Version 18.5.0: Mon Mar 11 20:40:32 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.251.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Footprint:       459.76 MB
Start time:      2019-06-04 07:34:17 +0200
End time:        2019-06-04 07:34:17 +0200
Num samples:     1 (1)
```

What has happened? How can I prevent this in the future?

Answer (score 7):

Welcome @user65526! So, generally speaking, more information is  needed for something like this. The closest I can guess is: some kernel extension, possible related to a graphics card or external video display (?) is getting hung up with Apple's "Power Nap" feature, also known as darkwake[s]. I'd recommended disabling the feature entirely, by entering in your terminal:

`sudo pmset -a darkwakes 0`

This will disable "Power Nap" in all cases. IMO its not a particularly useful feature anyway.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: It did not work for me. Do I have to do some of the usual resets in addition?

Answer (score 1):

My guess, in my case it happened because I simultaneously closed laptop and plugged off external HDMI display. I think I should first detach laptop from external devices, let handle it and then close laptop.

Report from my case:

```
Stackshot Reason: Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while entering darkwake on way to sleep. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74.
Failure code:: 0x2b24fc25 00000031

Event:           Sleep Wake Failure
Duration:        0.00s
Steps:           1
```

Comment: In fact, I have been very worried about using HDMI, since it seems to trigger problems with my MacBook Pro. Is there a way to eject the HDMI cable, like there is to eject a usb memory stick? Or do you just literally take it out of the socket?

Comment: I think there is no special actions should be taken before ejecting HDMI. And this situation is probably bug in rare use case

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause is **Docker for Mac**. After disabling Docker from startup on login, I haven't see any crash (for four days, at least).

Also, you can narrow down the problem quickly by shortening the hibernation time.

```
sudo pmset -a standbydelaylow 60 # default 10800
sudo pmset -a standbydelayhigh 65 # default 86400
```